# Load uncompressed collada file using iOS Scene Kit

Tags: ios, ios8, collada, scenekit

I need to load a collada file I downloaded on iOS, I intend to use Scene Kit to do it. But reading the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSceneSource_Class/) I found out that XCode compresses the collada files on compilation time, and Scene Kit can only load the compressed files.

After some research I ran into this [article](http://www.the-nerd.be/2014/11/07/dynamically-load-collada-files-in-scenekit-at-runtime/) where the author was able to find the scripts XCode uses and compress the files using them. The problem is that I'm not being able to run them on my server.

So my question is: Is there any other way to load collada files using scene kit? Or is there somewhere where I can find an algorithm to do the compression myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you can't upload compressed files on your server and cannot convert them on the fly on the server, I'm afraid that you will have to manually parse the Collada files and instantiate all the SceneKit objects yourself.

Comment: That was what I was trying to avoid, but I guess there is no other way, thanks

Comment: @Leonardo Note that there are now other options — with scene formats other than DAE (such as OBJ), you can use Model I/O to load unprocessed assets directly in iOS. However, it's always best to process your assets first. The best way to load assets for use in SceneKit is from a `.scn` file or `.scnassets` catalog — not only does that compress and format things in a way that loads quickly on device, it also lets you make sure you've got materials and other rendering parameters the way you want them, and add SceneKit features like physics & particles.