# SCNScene is nil when loading using `named: `

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit

I am using the following code to render a scene in scenekit and it works perfectly when the dae file is loaded from `art.scnassests` folder.

```
let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/idle.dae")
```

However I want to download the asset and apply it and I am getting an error

```
let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let scene = SCNScene(named: documentsURL.absoluteString+"idle.dae")
```

A file named `idle.dae` exists in the folder.

I get the error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

How to load the downloaded asset and apply dynamically?  What am I doing wrong?  Any pointers please? I am a noob to iOS programming.

Comment: someone added and deleted an answer .. If you will be kind enough to leave the answer back I would be grateful. You left best practices code to handle and maintain assets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless something has changed for iOS 11, you won't be able to download and instantiate a DAE file at runtime on iOS. They are compressed/compiled at build time using a utility named `scntool`.

Can you instead use one of the file formats supported by Model I/O? See https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/602/?time=320 for the original list (Alembic .abc, Polygon .ply Triangles .stl, WaveFront .obj), and https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/610/ for a quick discussion of Pixar's USD (Universal Scene Description).

If you're stuck with DAE files, Frederik Jacques has an article at https://the-nerd.be/2014/11/07/dynamically-load-collada-files-in-scenekit-at-runtime/ which outlines his experience reverse engineering the DAE processing pipeline. His technique allows downloaded SCN files which have been processed from DAE files on a server. 
See also [Load uncompressed collada file using iOS Scene Kit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27015580/load-uncompressed-collada-file-using-ios-scene-kit) (with comments by an authoritative source) and https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/38010.

Comment: I can move to scn. Can I download and apply the scn assets in realtime

Comment: You can download and use .SCN files in real time if you follow Frederik Jacques's pipeline. You'll need to run `scntool` on a Mac to convert each .DAE file to .SCN format. Using a Model I/O-supported format or Pixar USD would be simpler.

Comment: If you have any resources for swift on this please drop them here :) Thank you